# Why does Arquillian need test setup classed to be included in the Deployment

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jboss-arquillian

I have an Arquillian test class with some EJB's in a Jar Archive.

The test interacts with a local Kafka cluster on localhost:9092. 
The EJB's under test are Kafka message Consumers.

Before the test runs, I want to initialize the Kafka cluster by just running a startup() method. This should be done independently from the test archive.

But, apparently Arquillian needs ALL the classes used in the Kafka cluster to be in the Deployment archive. This shows by the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory from [Module "deployment.test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

This is not desirable, so I am looking for a way to start the Kafkacluster without having to add the entire classpath of the cluster.

I have tried to add a @BeforeClass method and then the cluster starts up fine, but the test then requires SASL authentication.

Note: when I first run the Kafkacluster in a separate main(), and then the test, all works fine. So basically I need a startup hook for the Arquillian test.

Comment: What I think it is happening is that you are running test inside the container, so since the test runs inside it, it requires everything to be deployed there (in this case the kafka things). You can do two things, the first one is running test on client side (IDE, Maven, ...) or if you need to run inside the container then use mix mode. Can you provide a github project so we can give you the correct direction better?

Comment: I have figured it out. I have created an embedded Zookeeper + Kafka cluster, which I start up before the test. Also I had to configure the PLAIN/PLAINTEXT settings to be able to run within Arquillian.